# Is distinct function deterministic? T-sql

Tags: t-sql

I have table like below. For distinct combination of user ID and Product ID SQL will select product bought from store ID 1 or 2? Is it determinictic?

[image]

My code

```
SELECT (DISTINCT CONCAT(UserID, ProductID)), Date, StoreID FROM X
```

Comment: If the answer is yes, or no, how would you expect it to make a difference? You've said "give me the distinct values from *these columns*" and that's all that you're left with - those columns, no others. They no longer represent the original rows in any way.

Comment: ok. Will this query return aa1,1,1 or aa1,2,2 every time, or randolmy one of it?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't valid syntax.   You can have

```
select [column_list] from X
```

or you can have

```
select distinct [column_list] from X
```

The difference is that the first will return one row for every row in the table while the second will return one row for every unique combination of the column values in your column list.

Adding "distinct" to a statement will reliably produce the same results every time unless the underlying data changes, so in this sense, "distinct" is deterministic.  However, it is not a function so the term "deterministic" doesn't really apply.

You may actually want a "group by" clause like the following (in which case you have to actually specify how you want the engine to pick values for columns not in your group):

```
select
    concat(UserId, ProductID)
,   min(Date)
,   max(Store)
from
    x
group by
    concat(UserId, ProductID)
```

Results:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oVeP.png)